# Threshold on contourf

Tags: matlab

I want two contour plot to show a threshold and I'm using

```
contourf(X,Y,Z,[-1,-1],'k');
contourf(X,Y,Z,[2,2],'w');
```

while X and Y a simple meshgrid.

I see that the matrix Z has values above -1 and above 1, so I'm expecting the two lines at -1 and 1 but I see only the first contour lines. What am I doing wrong? Do I get it wrong this property?

Edit: here an example

```
x = 0:5:180;
y = 0:5:355;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = 5*cos(X);

figure(1);## Heading ##
surf(X',Y',Z','EdgeColor','none');
view(2); colorbar;colormap(jet); hold on
contour(X',Y',Z',[-1,-1],'k','LineWidth',1);
contour(X',Y',Z',[2,2],'k','LineWidth',2);
legend('','1','2','Location','northeastoutside');
```

I saw that if I put the two `contour` in a new figure, the two are plotted. But when I use `surf`, I just see the [-1,-1] option.
Many thanks

edit2: using `pcolor` instead of `surf` (removing `,'EdgeColor','none'`)  gives me the correct plot...Why? What changes?

Comment: do you just mean `contourf(X,Y,Z,[-1,1],'k');`? Or maybe you forgot to `hold on`?

Comment: No I already have set `hold on` before the two contourf because I want them to overlap to a surf (2D). I mean I cannot see ` contourf(X,Y,Z,[1,1],'k');` and I don't understand why

Comment: post a [mcve] please

Comment: There you have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that contourf is not a 3D ploting function, its a 2D plotting function. So when you ask to plot contour lines, it will always plot them at z=0. So your `surf` plot is "on top of" the `contourf` for z>0, as you are setting `view(2)`.

Look at the example you gave, with a different view:

[image]

You can see both lines here.

`pcolor` plots a 2D image, not a 3D surface, so it works with `pcolor` or `imagesc`.